# How to solve for x in an inequality that contains factorials?

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion, factorial

I'm working on a Taylor polynomial remainder problem, and then i got stuck to this inequality right here

$(10.000)(2^{x+1})(e^{12}) < (x+1)!$

Using wolfram alpha the result is $x>12 but I don't understand the method.
How to solve for a variable in an inequality if factorial is involved?

Comment: Maybe some logarithms of both sides would help?

Comment: Exactly as John suggested, take the logarithm of both sides (with respect to some base; the choice is yours), and use the properties of the logarithm: $\log 2^{x + 1} = (x + 1) \log 2$ and $\log [(x + 1)!] = \sum_{i = 1}^{x + 1} \log i.$